# Mule - Copy the directory from HDFS

Tags: mule, hdfs

I need to copy the directory (/tmp/xxx_files/xxx/Output) head containing sub folders and files from [HDFS (Hadoop distributed file system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_distributed_file_system). I'm using [HDFS connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/hdfs-connector) but it seems it does not support this.

It always getting an error like:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file: /tmp/xxx_files/xxx/Output/
```

I don't see any option is HDFS connector for copying the files/directories inside the path specified. It is always expecting file names to be copied.

Is it possible to copy a directory head containing sub-folders and files using the HDFS connector from MuleSoft?

Comment: Could you please add some of your flow XML?

Answer (score 0):

As the technical documentation of the [HSFS connector on the official MuleSoft website](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/hdfs-connector) states, the code is hosted at the GitHub site of the connector:

> The Anypoint Connector for the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)
>   is used as a bi-directional gateway between applications. Its source
>   is stored at the HDFS Connector GitHub site.

What it does not state, that there is also [a more detailed technical documentation](http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-hadoop-connector/5.0.0/functional/user-manual.html) available on the GitHub site.

Here you can also find [different examples](http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-hadoop-connector/5.0.0/demo/common-operations.zip) how to use the connector for *basic* file-system operations.

The links seem to be broken in the official MuleSoft documentation.

You can find the repository here:

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-hadoop-connector

The operations are implemented in the [HdfsOperations java class](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-hadoop-connector/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/mule/extension/hdfs/internal/operation/HdfsOperations.java). (See also the [FileSystemApiService class](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-hadoop-connector/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/mule/extension/hdfs/internal/service/impl/FileSystemApiService.java))

*As you can see, the functionality you expect is not implemented. It is not supported out-of-the-box.*

You can't copy a directory head containing sub folders and files from HDFS without any further effort using the HDFS connector.